# How to pass a remote branch name to a name tag

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a jenkins job and I'm trying to save, in a txt, the name of a remote GIT branch that does a push & commit to use as part of a tag name. I tried several ways and so far the closest one is
`git branch -a> Name.txt`
but in my case it returns

- (HEAD detached at 7f11e2c)
- remotes / origin / ASTXXXX
- remotes / origin / develop
- remotes / origin / master

and I would only need to save ASTXXXX.

is this posible?
thanks

Comment: is `ASTXXXX` your current branch?

Comment: Anything is possible :) git branch is a porcelain command. Normally they are to be avoided when scripting. What you want is a plumbing command. If I understand you correctly you need something like this `git ls-remote --refs --heads --quiet | sed 's/^.*refs\/heads\///' | grep "your_search_string_here"`

Comment: Branch names don't actually *mean* anything in Git. Try not to depend on them (at all, ever). Jenkins uses a detached HEAD and, in effect, "forgets" the branch name. If Jenkins did not save it somewhere (I don't know if any version of Jenkins does, or if so, where to look) then it's just gone.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current branch to a text file you can do the following:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > Name.txt
```

EDIT: I am not sure, why youre jenkins job is detached, so you might not achieve your desired result.